# I can´t plot a geom_bar correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to improve my skills on R language and I found a problem.

```
#Load the library.
library(ggplot2)

#Execute a simple code
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, fill = am)) + geom_bar()
```

[image: I can´t post the image click here]

My main question is, what I'm doing bad, why the fill aesthetic has not been plotted

Comment: To get you started, take a look at `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, fill = as.factor(am))) + geom_bar()`

Answer (score 2):

Adrian. In the way that you are using it, with geom_bar(), fill should be a factor rather than a continuous variable.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, fill = as.character(am))) ## as.character or as.vector transform "am"
       + geom_bar()
```

[image]

To ilustate the differenece in ggplot's behavior between vector and numeric, look at this plot:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, fill = as.character(am), color = as.character(am), alpha = am))
      + geom_bar()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, never pass through mi mind check the class of data.